# How to sum particular values in a two-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, ruby

Let's say, I have this array

```
arr = [["Ready", 6], ["Draft", 3], ["To Repair", 4], ["Closed", 2]]
```

My goal is to show these data in percents instead of absolute values.  Here is what I want to get:

```
[["Ready", 0.5], ["Draft", 0.2], ["To Repair", 0.3], ["Closed", 0.2]]
```

That means I have to get the sum first. What I tried to do is:

```
arr.inject {|sum, a| sum + a[1]}
```

but this returns `TypeError Exception: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into Array`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a[0]` is a string; you want `a[1]`. And starting from `sum = 0` and not from `sum = ["Ready, 6]` is good - so you need the parameter to `inject`:

```
sum = arr.inject(0) { |sum, a| sum + a[1] }.to_f
arr.each { |el| el[1] /= sum }
# => [["Ready", 0.4], ["Draft", 0.2], ["To Repair", 0.26666666666666666], ["Closed", 0.13333333333333333]]
```

Comment: Ok! a[0] was just a typo but inject(0) is a good point, Thanks! i didn't understand how inject works

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the numbers, you should access the element at index 1, and provide an initial value for sum.

```
arr.inject(0) {|sum, a| sum + a[1]}
# => 15
```

Answer (score 1):

A lazy (but not the most effieicnt) way is:

```
arr.map(&:last).inject(:+)
```